# xamarin ios extension fails to run native code via P/Invoke without "Link All" Linker Behaviour

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, native

I have a xamarin.forms based project for uwp, iOS and android that successfully uses native code from a library written in **C/C++**.

For iOS I use an **iOS Bindings Library** project that implements a **P/Invoke** layer to the native code that is compiled to a fat library and linked into the bindings library. Everything works fine here.

Now I have added a **UNNotificationServiceExtension** which also works just fine for itself. I have added the same **iOS Bindings Library** that I use from my iOS app project as a reference to the **UNNotificationServiceExtension**, and can be successfully called up to the point where this Bindings Library's code makes a **P/Invoke** call into the native code. This will always throw a **System.EntryPointNotFoundException**.

I wonder, why my iOS app works just fine here and the unmodified Bindings Library exhibits this behaviour when used in the iOS **UNNotificationServiceExtension**.

Just some more data points: The **UNNotificationServiceExtension** supports the exact same processor architectures as my iOS app and both projects use **"Link Framework SDK only"** as the linker settings in both debug and release configurations. However, if I change the **UNNotificationServiceExtension**'s project's linker settings to **"Link all"**, everything works. It seems like the **"Link Framework SDKs Only"** setting strips away the **P/Invoked** native libraries from the resulting binary.

What do I have to do to force my native libraries from the Bindings Library to be included in the resulting binary? On a related subject I read sth about additional **mtouch** arguments. Can someone shed some light on this?

Any help appreciated,

--
Stefan

Comment: Hi, do you mean that `UNNotificationServiceExtension` will affect the **Link Framework SDKs Only**, and you not want to use **Link all**?

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang, it seems to me that using the standard setting ("Link Framework SDKs only") is removing my native code from the resulting binary. I have settled to using "Link All" (which leaves my native code in the binary, but is the most aggressive linker setting, AFAIK) and adding an additional mtouch argument "--linkskip=IntWSApiLibWrap" for the bindings library (with the name IntWSApiLibWrap), just as a safeguard. Is there a better solution to it?  -- Stefan

Comment: Generally, **Link Framework SDKs only** will  modify the assemblies to reduce the size of app. I think your solution should be the good choice. Otherwise, you could use **Don't Link**, but that will not reduce the size of app.